# Filter a vector

Tags: matlab

I would like to 'filter' a vector in an efficient way:

I have a first vector `M` containing values between 0 and 1 and an 'associated' vector `V`.

I want to create a new matrix that contains the elements of `V` for which the number in `M` is greater than 0.5.

I thought I could create a matrix like `M>0.5` which would contain 0's and 1's and keep the indexes of the ones, than create `filtered = V(indexes)`.

How can I get the `indexes` vector? (without a for loop)

Comment: You can do indexing with `logical`s, linear indexing or subscripts.  See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `M` and `V` are vectors of the same size, then

```
filteredV=V(M>0.5);
```

should work I think.

Answer (score 3):

Use find() to return indices which are non-zero.

```
M        = rand(1,5)
indexes  = find(M>0.5)
filtered = V(indexes)
```

BR
Magnus

Comment: While you are not wrong, the use of `find` is unnecessary.  See David's answer.  Right of you to provide `find` though as requested! +1

Comment: True, I just wanted to provide the indexes vector in the process (as requested in the question).